# Creating XML child adds odd attribute xmlns="", I need it removed

Tags: xml, powershell

I am tweaking an XMl file with powershell. When i create a childNode, automatically the attribute xmlns="" is added. How I can remove that? I simply need the node without that automatically been added.

Is there a parameter that has to be added in order to make it run properly, without any attribute to be added.

`$StageNode.AppendChild($XMLPackage.CreateElement("myChild"))`

And this is the outcome `<myChild xmlns="">`

Answer (score 0):

it did the trick by adding the NameSpaceURI parameter.

```
 $StageNode.AppendChild($XMLPackage.CreateElement("loginhibit", $StageNode.NamespaceURI))
```